# I switched to zsh but now less -S continues to wrap lines; how do I get the expected behavior?

Tags: unix, zsh

I switched to zsh recently, but now when I use less -S, it won't chop lines.  This is quite frustrating as I use less to look at wide data tables quite often.  Any idea how to fix the issue?

Thanks!
Uri

Answer (score 1):

zsh is probably messing with your stty settings and getting the columns wrong.  Try the fixes in the zsh faq under the heading "3.9: Why does my terminal act funny in some way?"

http://www.zsh.org/zsh/FAQ